# PostgreSQL error "unable to connect to server

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I start learning Django, and I had a problem using the Postegres database,
The server worked fine with sqlite3, but as soon as I declared Postgres in the project, the server stopped working

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql', # on utilise l'adaptateur postgresql
    'NAME': 'sarah disquaires', # le nom de notre base de donnees creee precedemment
    'USER': 'sarra', # attention : remplacez par votre nom d'utilisateur
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
```

}

I get this error:

```html
python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 220, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 77, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 55, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 259, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 235, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 219, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 200, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\sarra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I tried to migrate the base with python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate but didn't work,

I tested several solutions proposed on several sites, but did not work for me.

please help me solve this problem

Comment: If you read the error message you will find: `no password supplied`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

> no password supplied

So add the database password to the configurarion dictionary and re-run the migration

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me.  I did that, and gave me this error message.          

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: Hey, this means that probably in your model you have some foreign key. Is required to add the `on_delete` param on them. Should be enough to add `on_delete=models.CASCADE` to the foreign key. After that run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again